# Upgrade MariaDB Cluster 10.1 to 10.2

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, upgrade, galera

I'm planning to upgrade MariaDB Galera cluster from 10.1 to 10.2. Does anyone have details for steps to upgrade? My idea is something

1. Backup
2. Shutdown cluster
3. Uninstall 10.1 from each node
4. Install 10.2 to each node
5. Run mysql_upgrade at node which going to started first
6. Configure the first node and start
7. Configure rest of nodes and start them

I have three node cluster with maxscale loadbalancing.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the cluster in a rolling fashion, i.e. one node at a time without shutting down the others. That is one of the benefits of Galera cluster.

Make sure to avoid 10.2.9 or be ready to edit mysqld_safe, see [here](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13950?focusedCommentId=100911&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-100911).

For each node:

1. maxadmin: `set server $node-name maintenance`
2. Backup databases and config files
3. Shutdown the mysqld instance
4. Uninstall 10.1. On Redhat use `rpm -e --nodeps` rather than `yum remove` to avoid uninstalling packages such as postfix and cronie.
5. Install 10.2
6. Copy back config files, change any mariadb-10.1 sections to mariadb-10.2
7. Startup the mysqld instance
8. If you're on Redhat, CentOS or Fedora run `mysql_upgrade`
9. maxadmin: `clear server $node-name maintenance`